# IE6 textarea border on focus bug

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-6

I am writing a small web app, in which clicking a button slides down (jquery) a form that has a text input and a textarea.

The problem is that when the form slides down, the border of the textarea is invisible! The border appears only when it gets focus, and stays thereon. It stays visible even after it has lost focus since then.

What could the bug be? Is it documented?

CSS for that textarea:

```
#other-addresses textarea {
    border: 1px solid #BBBBBB;
    clear: left;
    font-size: 16px;
    height: 80px;
    padding: 3px;
    width: 350px;
}

input, textarea, button {
    font-family: 'Droid Sans',sans-serif;
}
```

PS: I have to consider IE6 compatibility too: it is built for an Indian audience, and in India, we still have [10% IE6 share](http://www.ie6countdown.com/) :(

PS: I do have a workaround: when the slide down completes, I have javascript `focus()` and `blur()` that textarea quickly. But I'm more interested in the root cause :)

Comment: +1 - A rather interesting case. Could you post some code and CSS related to the textarea?

Comment: yep, will post all css that firebug finds for that textarea

Comment: I've long since stopped supporting IE6, but I remember it well in my nightmares. I don't recall anything exactly like this, but IE6 has so many bugs that your description really doesn't surprise me. I haven't been able to find anything documented about this, but that's mainly because every search term I tried with IE6 in it was swamped with people talking about other IE6 bugs. To be honest, I'd just accept that this is the way IE6 is, and move on. You've got a work around for it already, so you'll be fine.

Comment: yep, that's the approach I've had to settle with. Let this question be a testimonial and a reminder to the future generations that some things in life don't have an explanation - you just have to deal with them :)

Answer (score 0):

In cases where some Javascript updates the DOM or style settings. You can force your css style to be more important that what the Javascript/jQuery.

```
textarea
{
    border:solid 1px black!important;
}
```

To check if it will work in your case we would need you to post your code or a link to an example page.

Comment: its not a CSS problem - I already have CSS that gets triggered on focus.